# Web2py - what are the official list of arguments for sessions2trash.py?

Tags: python, web2py

sessions2trash.py source has the following:

```
Typical usage:

    # Delete expired sessions every 5 minutes
    nohup python web2py.py -S app -M -R scripts/sessions2trash.py &

    # Delete sessions older than 60 minutes regardless of expiration,
    # with verbose output, then exit.
    python web2py.py -S app -M -R scripts/sessions2trash.py -A -o -x 3600 -f -v

    # Delete all sessions regardless of expiry and exit.
    python web2py.py -S app -M -R scripts/sessions2trash.py -A -o -x 0
```

Is there a canonical list of arguments somewhere? Thanks!

**Update:** found it by browsing the source. Is there a standard way to show the help text? `python web2py.py -S app -M -R scripts/sessions2trash.py` doesn't show any help.

Answer (score 1):

Found it in a section of the source:

```
parser.add_option('-f', '--force',
                  action='store_true', dest='force', default=False,
                  help=('Ignore session expiration. '
                        'Force expiry based on -x option or auth.settings.expiration.')
                  )
parser.add_option('-o', '--once',
                  action='store_true', dest='once', default=False,
                  help='Delete sessions, then exit.',
                  )
parser.add_option('-s', '--sleep',
                  dest='sleep', default=SLEEP_MINUTES * 60, type="int",
                  help='Number of seconds to sleep between executions. Default 300.',
                  )
parser.add_option('-v', '--verbose',
                  default=0, action='count',
                  help="print verbose output, a second -v increases verbosity")
parser.add_option('-x', '--expiration',
                  dest='expiration', default=None, type="int",
                  help='Expiration value for sessions without expiration (in seconds)',
                  )
```

Note that since we're calling sessions2trash from web2py, we have to precede these arguments with -A, so web2py knows they're for the child script and not web2py.py itself.